# Neater way to assign to variable from Object

Tags: javascript, object, variables, ecmascript-6

Is there a neater way to assign the values to objects rather than what I have:

My code:

```
let val1 = result.data.data.table.val1;
let val2 = result.data.data.table.test.val2;
let val3 = result.data.data.table.val3;
let val4 = result.data.data.table.val4;
let val5 = result.data.data.table.val5;
```

Is there a neater way to assign this, a one-liner?

Comment: If you find yourself making property/variable names like "val1", "val2", etc, you probably should consider using an array.

Comment: Does the second one really have `.test`, unlike the others?

Comment: @Barmar, test has another object, `val2`

Comment: @Pointy I'm guessing that those are just example names, they're not really numbered.

Comment: @Barmar well I've learned not to make too many assumptions around here

Comment: @Pointy The fact that `val2` is nested deeper than the rest means it's not really an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is destructuring.

```
let {val1, test: {val2}, val3, val4, val5} = result.data.data.table;
```